# web2py default formstyle not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, web2py

In my `appconfig.ini` file the default `formstyle` is `bootstrap3_inline`. But when the form is displayed in the browser, the form elements are shown vertically, one below the other, and the page-source says the form class is `form-horizontal`. I tried using all the other options for `formstyle`, but could not get the bootstrap `form-inline`. I am using Chrome browser.

I want to have the 'form-inline' style because my form has only a few elements, and a lot of screen space is unused with the 'form-horizontal' style. How do I get the form to be displayed in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bootstrap3_inline` name is somewhat misleading, as it is really intended to produce a [Bootstrap horizontal form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal). The term "inline" in this context is just intended to mean that each form field displays the label and the input *inline* (as opposed to the default, with the input displayed below the label).

To convert to a true Bootstrap inline form, you can simply change the class of the `FORM` object after it has been constructed:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.mytable).process()
form['_class'] = 'form-inline'
```

If you want to apply this style to multiple forms or make it the default, you can create a custom `formstyle` function based on the `boostrap3_inline` formstyle:

```
from gluon.sqlhtml import formstyle_bootstrap3_inline_factory
def inline_form(form, fields):
    form = formstyle_bootstrap3_inline_factory(3)(form, fields)
    form['_class'] = 'form-inline'
    return form
```

Then you can apply this style to a single form:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.mytable, formstyle=inline_form)
```

Or make it the default `formstyle`:

```
response.formstyle = inline_form
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Anthony. The  online book says the `formstyle` "bootstrap" uses the `the bootstrap 2.3 form class "form-horizontal"` So I presume both `bootstrap3_inline` and `bootstrap` refer to the same style class.